# Is it possible to recover a value which i deleted form SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just deleted some record from my database table.i just want to retrieve those data is this possible?

i don't have any backup of the database

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: May help you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/how-can-i-recover-data-from-the-ldf-file

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you're using SQL 2016+ and your table is temporal table please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [yourTable] FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
```